# System Arithmetic Exception: Delphi calling C# DLL via C++/CLI wrapper

Tags: c#, delphi, interop, c++-cli, pointer-arithmetic

I have a C# DLL that uses the XslCompiledTransform class for xml manipulations. I stole a C++/CLI wrapper for the C# DLL.

When using Delphi 5 to implement the C++/CLI wrapper, I receive a System Arithmetic error. Here is the Delphi 5 declaration:

```
procedure XsltMethod(XmlPath, XsltPath: PWideChar); cdecl; external 'ahma.dll';
```

The body of the C# public method creates a new XslCompiledTransform object and the exception pops up right when the newly created object runs its **load** method. For example:

```
XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
xslt.Load(XsltFile);
```

As mentioned earlier, the exception thrown from the .NET DLL is a System Arithmetic Exception. This only happens when called from a Delphi executable.

I guess I should mention calling the object's **load** method again works fine. So catching the exception and running the method for a second "pass" acts like a popup blocker. But for exceptions, of course.

Comment: Can't fault the post for not being detailed enough, that's for sure. It might actually help to codense things a bit, and put everything except short snippets in files to which you like. Might get more people to read it that way.

Comment: Ha! Yea I'm a noob. Thanks for being patient with me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you suffer from differences in the Floating-Point Control Register as stated [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326219). Also see [this](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=8399) QC report. You could try calling Set8087CW($133F); in your Delphi program. Be cautious of floating point problems in your Delphi code after that.

Answer (score 2):

Random thoughts:

- I think you should start by debugging your assembly from Visual Studio. Insert a messagebox or other wait statement in the Delphi code, then attach to process from Visual Studio. Tracing the C# might provide a couple of hints on what is going wrong. If you can't get it working, at least add logging of the incoming parameters.

  In delphi, you don't need to escape backslashes.

  Are you sure the E0434F4D is not some innocent first-chance exception? If you do not debug (or continue from the JIT debugger exception stop, which I'm not entirely sure is possible with Delphi 5), is the behaviour indeed faulty?

  Could we please refer to "native Win32 assembly" as "DLL", like we used to call them for the past 20 years? :-)

Comment: +1 for the "native Win32 assembly" comment.  We *know* what "assembly" is, and it's about the furthest thing from managed code that you can possibly find. :P

Comment: I've got three words for you: ctrl. alt. c. Debugging Delphi wouldn't be the same without it. :D